# Getting Unexpected Token error on running Jest/React test

Tags: reactjs, configuration, jestjs

I am running jest/react test and getting the following error:

```
/Users/sn/Documents/react-testing-with-jest-master/starter/CountdownTimer/jest.config.js:2
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is my jest.config.js:

```
{
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "Clock": "<rootDir>/app/components/Clock.jsx",
        "CountdownForm": "<rootDir>/app/components/CountdownForm.jsx",
        "Countdown": "<rootDir>/app/components/Countdown.jsx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have named the file `jest.config.js` instead of `jest.config.json`, you are expected to export a valid JavaScript object.

Either:

1. Rename the file to `jest.config.json` or
2. Export a valid JS object:

`jest.config.js`:

```
{
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "jsx"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        Clock: "<rootDir>/app/components/Clock.jsx",
        CountdownForm: "<rootDir>/app/components/CountdownForm.jsx",
        Countdown: "<rootDir>/app/components/Countdown.jsx"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dane. How to export valid JS Object?

Comment: Now I am getting:  moduleNameMapper: {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: try with ur previous file, and add `"json"` to `"moduleFileExtensions"` https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulefileextensions-array-string